# Get unique objects on has_and_belongs_to_many

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have 3 entities: Feeds, Episodes, Series. Feeds `has_and_belongs_to_many` Episodes. Episodes `belongs_to` Series.

What I would like is all the series for a feed, and the number of episodes, in that series, in that feed.

Answer (score 1):

You can produce the complete list of all series for a given set of episodes by first finding the IDs of all series...

```
# uniq insures that any duplicates are removed
ids = feed.episodes.map(&:series_id).uniq
```

And then finding the series themselves:

```
series = Series.where(id: ids)
```

You can find the number of episodes for each series with a simple `count`:

```
series.each do |s|
  puts "Series #{s.name} has #{s.episodes.count} episodes"
end
```

Comment: Unfortunately the relation between episodes and series is the other way. No episode_id on series.

Answer (score 1):

[meagar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/229044/meagar)’s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21070674/get-unique-objects-on-has-and-belongs-to-many/21070687?noredirect=1#21070687) led me to the following solution:

```
ids = @feed.episodes.pluck(:series_id)
@series = Series.find(ids)

@episode_counts = Hash.new(0)
ids.each do |id|
  @episode_counts[id] += 1
end
```

Comment: Yes, sorry, `pluck` is the way to go. I don't know why I wrote `pluck` in my first answer and `map(&:series_id)` in my updated answer :|